# Ansible with "Alternative Directory Layout" and using vaults

Tags: ansible, ansible-vault

I am trying to use the [Alternative Directory Layout](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_best_practices.html#alternative-directory-layout) and ansible-vaults within. 
But when i run my playbook, variables which are vault encrypted could not resolve with that directory structure. So what iam doing wrong?

I execute via:

```
ansible-playbook -i inventories/inv/hosts playbooks/inv/invTest.yml --check --ask-vault
```

Here is my structure:

```
.
├── inventories
│   ├── inv
│   │   ├── group_vars
│   │   │   ├── var.yml
│   │   │   └── vault.yml
│   │   └── hosts
│   └── staging
│       ├── group_vars
│       │   ├── var.yml
│       │   └── vault.yml
│       └── hosts
├── playbooks
│   ├── staging
│   │   └── stagingTest.yml
│   └── inv
│       ├── invTest.retry
│       └── invTest.yml
└── roles
    ├── basic-linux
    │   ├── defaults
    │   │   └── main.yml
    │   └── tasks
    │       └── main.yml
    ├── test
    │   ├── defaults
    │   │   └── main.yml
    │   └── tasks
    │       └── main.yml
    └── webserver
        ├── defaults
        │   └── main.yml
        ├── files
        ├── handler
        │   └── main.yml
        ├── tasks
        │   └── main.yml
        └── templates
```

this is my hosts file (`inventories/inv/hosts`):

```
[inv]
testvm-01    ansible_ssh_port=22    ansible_ssh_host=172.16.0.101    ansible_ssh_user=root
testvm-02    ansible_ssh_port=22    ansible_ssh_host=172.16.0.102    ansible_ssh_user=root
```

playbook (`playbooks/inv/invTest.yml`):

```
---
  - name: this is test
    hosts: inv
    roles:
      - { role: ../../roles/test }
...
```

role which uses the vault encrypted var (`roles/test/tasks/main.yml`):

```
---
  - name: create test folder
    file:
        path: "/opt/test/{{ app_user }}/"
        state: directory
        owner: "{{ default_user }}"
        group: "{{ default_group }}"
        mode: 2755
        recurse: yes
...
```

var which points to vault (inventories/inv/group_vars/var.yml):

```
---
app_user: '{{ vault_app_user }}'
app_pass: '{{ vault_app_pass }}'
...
```

vault file (`ansible-vault edit inventories/inv/group_vars/vault.yml`):

```
vault_app_user: itest
vault_app_pass: itest123
```

The error message iam getting is something like this:

> FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "the field 'args' has an invalid value, which appears to include a variable that is undefined. The error was: {{ app_user }}: 'app_user' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to have been in 'roles/test/tasks/main.yml': but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n  - name: create test folder\n    ^ here\n"}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You define variable `app_user` in a file called `var.yml` stored in group_vars folder.

In your execution line you point to the `inventories/inv/hosts` as your inventory directory.

It doesn't matter what strings you used in this path -- from Ansible's point of view it sees only:

```
hosts
group_vars
├── var.yml
└── vault.yml
```

It will read `var.yml` for a host group called `var` and `vault.yml` for a host group called `vault`.

In your case -- never.

---

You likely wanted to organise your files this way:

```
inventories
└── production
    ├── group_vars
    │   └── inv
    │       ├── var.yml
    │       └── vault.yml
    └── hosts
```

This way, files in `group_vars/inv` will be read for hosts in group `inv`.